# General comprehensions in Scala

Tags: scala, list-comprehension

As far as I understand, the Scala for-comprehension notation relies on the first generator to define how elements are to be combined. Namely, `for (i <- list) yield i` returns a list and `for (i <- set) yield i` returns a set.

I was wondering if there was a way to specify how elements are combined independently of the properties of the first generator. For instance, I would like to get *"the set of all elements from a given list"*, or *"the sum of all elements from a given set"*. The only way I have found is to first build a list or a set as prescribed by the for-comprehension notation, then apply a transformation function to it - building a useless data structure in the process.

What I have in mind is a general "algebraic" comprehension notation as it exists for instance in Ateji PX:

```
`+ { i | int i : set }               // the sum of all elements from a given set
set() { i | int i : list }           // the set of all elements from a given list
concat(",") { s | String s : list }  // string concatenation with a separator symbol
```

Here the first element (`` `+ ``, `set()`, `concat(",")`) is a so-called "monoid" that defines how elements are combined, independently of the structure of the first generator (there can be multiple generators and filters, I just tried to keep the examples concise).

Any idea about how to achieve a similar result in Scala while keeping a nice and concise notation ? As far as I understand, the for-comprehension notation is hard-wired in the compiler and cannot be upgraded.

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 12):

### About the for comprehension

The `for` comprehension in scala is syntactic sugar for calls to `flatMap`, `filter`, `map` and `foreach`. In exactly the same way as calls to those methods, the type of the target collection leads to the type of the returned collection. That is:

```
list map f   //is a List
vector map f // is a Vector
```

This property is one of the *underlying design goals* of the scala collections library and would be seen as desirable in most situations.

### Answering the question

You do not need to construct any intermediate collection of course:

```
(list.view map (_.prop)).toSet //uses list.view

(list.iterator map (_.prop)).toSet //uses iterator

(for { l <- list.view} yield l.prop).toSet //uses view

(Set.empty[Prop] /: coll) { _ + _.prop } //uses foldLeft
```

Will all yield Sets without generating unnecessary collections. My personal preference is for the first. In terms of *idiomatic* scala collection manipulation, each "collection" comes with these methods:

```
//Conversions
toSeq
toSet
toArray
toList
toIndexedSeq
iterator
toStream

//Strings
mkString

//accumulation
sum
```

The last is used where the element type of a collection has an implicit `Numeric` instance in scope; such as:

```
Set(1, 2, 3, 4).sum //10
Set('a, 'b).sum //does not compile
```

Note that the String concatenation example in scala looks like:

```
list.mkString(",")
```

And in the **scalaz** FP library might look something like (which uses `Monoid` to sum Strings):

```
list.intercalate(",").asMA.sum
```

*Your suggestions do not look anything like Scala; I'm not sure whether they are inspired by another language.*

Answer (score 4):

`foldLeft`? That's what you're describing.

The sum of all elements from a given set:

```
(0 /: Set(1,2,3))(_ + _)
```

the set of all elements from a given list

```
(Set[Int]() /: List(1,2,3,2,1))((acc,x) => acc + x)
```

String concatenation with a separator symbol:

```
("" /: List("a", "b"))(_ + _) // (edit - ok concat a bit more verbose:
("" /: List("a", "b"))((acc,x) => acc + (if (acc == "") "" else ",")  + x)
```

Comment: `(0 /: Set(1,2,3))(_ + _)` is more idiomatically written `Set(1,2,3).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)` or, better yet, `Set(1,2,3).sum`. This latter form is the only truly declarative construct, and the only form that will also work in the face of parallel collections.  Likewise, `(Set[Int]() /: List(1,2,3,2,1))((acc,x) => acc + x)` is better written as `List(1,2,3,2,1).toSet`

Comment: Also, `("" /: List("a", "b"))((acc,x) => acc + (if (acc == "") "" else ",")  + x)` is better written as `List("a", "b") mkString ","`

Comment: @Kevin, the question is about what construct to use to start with a first element, feed it to one or more generators and combining them with a function. For one generator, `foldLeft` fits that description. The fact that `sum` or `toSet` exist was not my point, given that oxbow_lakes had already mentioned those.

Answer (score 1):

You can also force the result type of the for comprehension by explicitly supplying the implicit CanBuildFrom parameter as scala.collection.breakout and specifying the result type.

Consider this REPL session:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)

scala> val res = for(i <- list) yield i
res: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)

scala> val res: Set[Int] = (for(i <- list) yield i)(collection.breakOut)
res: Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

It results in a type error when not specifying the CanBuildFrom explicitly:

```
scala> val res: Set[Int] = for(i <- list) yield i
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Set[Int]
       val res: Set[Int] = for(i <- list) yield i
                                 ^
```

For a deeper understanding of this I suggest the following read:

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use for comprehensions and still be able to combine your values in some result value you could do the following.

```
case class WithCollector[B, A](init: B)(p: (B, A) => B) {
  var x: B = init
  val collect = { (y: A) => { x = p(x, y) } }
  def apply(pr: (A => Unit) => Unit) = {
    pr(collect)
    x
  }
}

// Some examples
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // It's still functional
    val r1 = WithCollector[Int, Int](0)(_ + _) { collect =>
      for (i <- 1 to 10; if i % 2 == 0; j <- 1 to 3) collect(i + j)
    }

    println(r1) // 120

    import collection.mutable.Set

    val r2 = WithCollector[Set[Int], Int](Set[Int]())(_ += _) { collect =>
      for (i <- 1 to 10; if i % 2 == 0; j <- 1 to 3) collect(i + j)
    }

    println(r2) // Set(9, 10, 11, 6, 13, 4, 12, 3, 7, 8, 5)
  }

}
```